# How to achieve internal website link click to execture something then to go to clicked link using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to achieve the following:

user clicks on the inbound website link and javascript/jquery executes something first, and when execution is over then loads next page.

I tried several techniques I found around but nothing really works for me (or I did something wrong).

Specifically, I want to run JS animation before moving to next page.

Comment: Use Event Prevent Default, perform needed actions, return True. If you need more help, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I tought some browsers block Even.preventDefaul when it comes to link click.

Comment: Could you show your actual code that showcases that *"JS animation"* and anything you tried so far?

Comment: @Wed See Browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to do this:

1. Set a `click` listener to the link
2. Use `e.preventDefault()` to prevent direct redirection
3. Run the animation, I assume it will take some time, so use `await` to continue when it finishes
4. redirect the page to the `href` attribute of the clicked link

```js
redirectLink.addEventListener("click", redirect);
async function redirect(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     await runAnimation();
     console.log("redirecting...");
     window.location = e.target.href;
}
function runAnimation(){
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          console.log("running animation...");
          resolve();
     });
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/" id="redirectLink">Redirect</a>
```

Comment: As well as you (hopefully) don't use inline `style=""` attributes, stop using and suggesting new developers to use inline `on*=""` handlers. JS should be in one place only and that's your script, not in an un-debuggable manner disseminated throughout your HTML file. Use the preferred `Element.addEventListener()` instead.

Comment: @MajedBadawi when I click that link, I end up on /undefined page. Probably something wrong with e.target.href value or passing it down.

Comment: @Wed does your ``<a>`` tag has the ``href`` attribute with the link and try to debug if ``console.log(e.target)`` shows normally in the function. Feel free to share the code for more details

Comment: @MajedBadawi
19:29:10.709 about-us.html:383 running animation...
19:29:10.710 about-us.html:377 redirecting...
19:29:10.716 VM2160 dls.js:213 data layer push: {event: "gtm.linkClick", gtm.element: a#redirectLink, gtm.elementClasses: "", gtm.elementId: "redirectLink", gtm.elementTarget: "", …}
19:29:10.808 about-us.html:378 GET https://example.com/undefined 404 (Not Found)
redirect @ about-us.html:378
async function (async)
redirect @ about-us.html:376
19:29:10.871 Navigated to https://example.com/undefined
19:29:11.356 undefined:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: